# Google django-allauth config

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have been able to successfully configure django-allauth with my Django app. When i attempt to signup via Google, i see a Sign Up form getting shown before login, which is prompting user to enter username, email etc. like the following:

> **Sign Up** You are about to use your Google account to login to example.com. As a final step, please complete the following form:
>
> Username:
>
> E-mail (optional):
>
> Sign Up »

Is there a config. which i can use to bypass this form? Please suggest how to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. The form was popping up because the Gmail user email ID that i was trying to login with was same as the Super Admin Email ID created via "django-admin createsuperuser" command.